# Is a perfect infinite range interactions the same thing as no interaction at all?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics

By perfectly infinite range I mean a potential which is a constant, no matter the distance.

Would one just recover a single-particle behaviour?

Whatever any particle does, everything else has to mimic it...

Comment: if V is a constant then the field is zero

Comment: Did you mean a _force_ which is constant, no matter the distance?

Comment: Yeah I probably meant force... I’ll ask another question I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment if the potential is a constant then you have no force and therefore you recover a free theory that is every particle motion is uniform and rectilinear. For example you can see this from the variation of the action or directly from the Euler-Lagrange equations or Newton's equations. Take for example the Euler Lagrange equations, you'd have in classical mechanics 
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}} + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial {q}} = 0
$$

Since the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ depends on the coordinates $q$ only through the potential wich is constant you have that the second term is $0$, so all that's left is the equation for the free theory:

$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}  = 0
$$